# How to disable automatic updates on Moto phone with Android Pie

Tags: ota-update, motorola-moto-g, 9.0-pie

I have magisk installed because of which updates are failing. Every few hours it will download the update in background, and try to install, and fail.

It's draining my battery and consuming my limited wifi internet.

I want to disable them until I have sometime to uninstall magisk and update it manually.

Note: I am fine with annoying notifications but don't want wifi/battery issues.

Comment: Which Motorola Phone is it?

Comment: @Firelord G6 Plus